# Best way to prevent running malicious/virus macro on PC

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, security, vba, macros

I've got a question. Could You provide some hints/solutions about preventing running suspicious macro's in Office apps? What I've already know:

- there is a possibility to turn off all macro's without exception via GPO
- I can turn on running macro's for selected users (User Group) via GPO, but only allow to run digitally signed macro's
- to sign a macro, I need to get a certificate (but not self-created by selfcert.exe, I think)

Basically, I need to run macro's for selected users, but I want to run it as safe as possible. It's all about controlling macro's. Any advise will be useful.

Comment: Your question isn't clear, what actually do you need? You've already listed the available options, do you need more information on them? Aren't those fitting for your need and you need something else?

Comment: Exactly, I need more information about other solutions. One of them I wrote in my question. I'm looking for different approach to this matter, so I could select the most secure one :)

Comment: Microsoft provides ADMX Office templates, using the templates, you can modify the GPO rules on macros. Your question as written is to broad or shows very little research effort on your part.

Comment: I'll agree that my question is too broad, but disagree that I did a little research, because solution, which I wrote in my question, involves using ADMX Office template, which You mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

I download many files.  To me, the obvious danger is the file automatically running a miscreant macro by itself.  To prevent this, I disable Events before I open the file:

```
Sub GetFile()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\TestFolder\suspicious.xlsm"
End Sub
```

This gives me the opportunity to review all macros before running any of them.

***Notes:***

If macros are enabled, most macros will run if YOU run them.
However some macros will run all by themselves *(Event macros)*.  These Event macros may run when the workbook is opened or when a certain sheet is selected or when a certain cell is selected, or when a worksheet is printed, etc.   I don't want this automatic behaviour to occur until I have review all the macros.  the line:

```
 Application.EnableEvents = False
```

switches off this behaviour.

Comment: OK, that's something :) Could You briefly explain, what does Application.EnableEvents do?

Comment: @Boba_Fett  Se my ***Notes***